# Keras vs. tf.keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I'm a bit confused in choosing between [Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/tree/master/keras) (keras-team/keras) and [tf.keras](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/keras) (tensorflow/tensorflow/python/keras/) for my new research project.

There is a debate that **Keras** isn't owned by anyone, so people are happier to contribute in and it'll be much easier to manage the project in the future. ‬

On the other side, ‪**tf.keras** is owned by Google, so more rigorous test and maintenance. Moreover, it seems this is a better option for taking advantage of new features which are presenting in Tensorflow v.2.

So, to start a data science (machine learning) project (in the research phase), that both are okay at the beginning, which one do you choose?!‬

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893528/keras-vs-tensorflow-python-keras-which-one-to-use

Comment: Another explanation on this:  https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/

Answer (score 22):

From [Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras) repo.:

> Keras is a high-level neural networks API, written in Python and
>   capable of running on top of TensorFlow, CNTK, or Theano.

And

> Before installing Keras, please install one of its backend engines:
>   TensorFlow, Theano, or CNTK. We recommend the TensorFlow backend.

So Keras is a skin (an API). TensorFlow has decided to include this skin inside itself as `tf.keras`. Since Keras provides APIs that TensorFlow has already implemented (unless CNTK and Theano overtake TensorFlow which is unlikely), `tf.keras` would keep up with Keras in terms of API diversity. Therefore, I would suggest to go with `tf.keras` which keeps you involved with only one, higher quality repo. instead of two, which means less headache.

> Which one do you choose?!

`tf.keras‬`.

Answer (score 10):

This [tweet](https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1174018651449544704?s=19) from François Chollet suggests to use **tf.keras**.

> We recommend you switch your Keras code to tf.keras.
>
> Both Theano and CNTK are out of development. Meanwhile, as Keras backends, they represent less than 4% of Keras usage. The other 96% of users (of which more than half are already on tf.keras) are better served with tf.keras.
>
> Keras development will focus on tf.keras going forward.
>
> Importantly, we will seek to start developing tf.keras in its own standalone GitHub repository at keras-team/keras in order to make it much easier for 3rd party folks to contribute.
>
> Keras has never been moving faster than now